# Blend two images sequences one into another in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, image-sequence

In compositor, I have two image sequence input nodes.
Both image sequences contain 300 images.

In the output (either Viewer, Composite or File Output) I want to blend from "100% first ,0% second image sequence" to "0% first, 100% second image sequence".

I tried to use a Mix node which takes the two image sequences as inputs, but per default, it seems as if both image sequences are mixed together at the output, even at factor 0.

It really is of essential importance for me to have image sequence 1 exclusively at the beginning and number 2 in the end.
Meaning the first image at the output should be exactly the first image from sequence 1 and the last image at the output should be exactly the last image of sequence 2.
In the middle, I wanted to look for the "sweet spot" of blending with the factor setting.
How can I achieve something like this?

Here is the current compositor in order to support my description:

[image]

Edit: Here is a demo file with only single image inputs, but the same effect.
I want at a factor of 0, that the output should be exactly the same as the upper input image.

[image]

Comment: What leads you think -images are already mixed a bit at Factor zero (or one)? By switching image directly to Viewer and Mix output socket I don't see a difference. Thanks for more info.

Comment: You are correct that at first glimpse it looks like there is no difference. I was confused also when I made this small example and checked if everything is "working" as expected. Then I saved the image from the rendered view to disk as png and compared it with an image viewer (Irfanview) to the one that I input and the "rendered" image was slightly but clearly brighter than the original one.

Comment: Isn't that caused by Colour Management that is by default set to Filmic?

Comment: Maybe it is... I'll check. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is going into the right direction. When I change to standard in the render properties, the viewer immediately reacts and the output gets less bright. Just what I want. Now, the only problem left is that the rendered output is still brighter, although the color management of the output properties should follow the scene and also the override seems to make no difference. I'm confused...

Comment: The demo file you've uploaded shows first image if I set the mix factor to 0 and the second if I set it to 1. So far there is everything working as expected. But as I commented under the answer, the second sequence just looks like it's a duplicate of the first one - so maybe the mix factor just switches between one and the same?

Comment: @Gordon see my comment below ;-)

Comment: @Kiamur As I said in the comment above, the sample file works absolutely fine. If I set the factor to 0 and render it, I get image 1, I set the factor to 1 and get image 2. Setting it to 0.5 gets me a mixture of both images. I realize that 0001_08.png and 0001_80.png might look similar at first glance, but trlust me I've seen the difference. And Blender itself doesn't just glance quickly - the .001 is only added if two names are _exactly_ the same, since it doesn't allow the same name twice.

Comment: @Gordon, the explanation for the upper screenshot is that both image sequences have actually the same file names, but they are from different folders. So that is why Blender renamed one of them with .001. For the sample file, I tried to be more precise and renamed the images before I added them to the image nodes. vklidu pointed in the correct direction, because my projects are all initially set to "filmic" in the color management properties. As I commented above, the change to "standard" made the output look more correct in the viewer node, but I'm still struggling to get it rendered.

Comment: But if neither the screenshot nor the sample file shows the actual image sequence it's hard to find the problem. As I said, the sample file worked fine, I'm also using _Filmic_ and I can clearly see a difference when mixing. So it seems I don't understand what the problem is or the problem is simply not reproducible with the sample file.

Comment: @Gordon, I think the reason why you don't see the problem is, because I was not precise enough in the beginning, because I totally missed that "filmic" issue. Can you somehow export the input images from my sample blend file? Then compare these input images to the rendered output outside of blender. You'll realize that the rendered output will look different than the original input file. When you are within the "filmic" domain inside Blender, you will not see any difference by switching the input node directly to the viewer, because filmic is applied here already to the viewer.

Comment: To clarify more: The image sequence I try to manipulate here is "scene 6" in an overall animation I'm currently working on. So it is very important that this image sequence will fit seamless to "scene 5". When I tried to mix these two images sequences, I realized afterwards, that scene 5 and scene 6 do not fit seamless into each other because the first image of scene 6 was slightly brighter. Because I just not had this "filmic" option in my mind, I blamed the mix node to change the image, even if it is set to 0. Hope this clarifies it a little more. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139034/discussion-between-gordon-brinkmann-and-kiamur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with the hint of vklidu, regarding the "filmic" setting in the color management properties and the following discussion with Gordon Brinkmann.

Explanation:
I asked the wrong question due to my lack of awareness of the "filmic" option.
I believed, that the Mix Node is affecting my input images although the factor was set to 0 or 1 respectively.
By comparing the input image to the image rendered out external of Blender (with a simple image viewer), there is a difference when the Color management is set to filmic. The images are exactly the same, when the color management is set to standard.

The Mix node works just as expected!

For completeness, here are the original input file, the filmic output and the standard output (in exactly that order).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally, the setting I had to change

[image]

Be aware, that color management settings are at different places, for different purposes (view, render, file output).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right - just animate **Fac** (*Factor*) value of *Mix* node, add keyframe at frame 1 with value zero ...

[image]

... than move timeline at last frame, set value to 1 and add another keyframe (with cursor hovering above value field press "I" or right click for context menu).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort answering. However, this is the issue I'm actually asking about. I thought "factor=0" leads to 100% image 1 and "factor=1" leads to 100% second image. This is not the case. Even at "factor=0" it seems as if both images are mixed together already a little bit. I'm looking for a way to have a mixer which does not mix anything if the factor is at its limit.

Comment: @Kiamur As vklidu stated, that's how it works and you understand the mixing correctly. However, what I see in your screenshot above is ####.png for the first image sequence and ####.png.001 for the second image sequence. This looks like the second is a duplicate of the first one - in this case they are the same (the preview image looks the same, too), so how would you recognize which one the _Mix RGB_ really shows?

Comment: The difference of the input images is very subtle. Both in view and naming. The images are named 0001_08.png and 0001_80.png. They were rendered from the same scene, but one with 8 transparency light bounces and the other with 80. Since I'm a beginner, I realized pretty far in my project that I need more light bounces than 8 in my scene, when the sun will rise (later in the animation). So I want to fade the 8-images into the 80-images, in order to "fix my mistake in post" ;-) (The screenshot from my initial post is not from the sample blend file I provided, download that and see for yourself).